# Project Euler (Python) #14 - Extracting Data from a "if" loop

Tags: python

This is [question 14 in project euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), but I'm having trouble not with creating the loops ... but pulling/evaluating numbers that I have created from the loop. I'm currently going through PE to learn how to use python.

Here my my code with annotations:

```
import time # gets the time functionality

start = time.time() # starts the timer

def seq(x, count = 1): # This is a function, with the parameter of x and counting

    seq = [x] # a data frame for the Collatz Sequence with x being placed in there

    if x < 1:

        return count

    while x > 1:

        count += 1

        if x % 2 == 0: # determines if the number is even or not

            x = x / 2

        else:
            x = (3 * x) + 1

    seq.append(count) # adds all the answers generated to the seq data fram

max = [0,0] # define a new placeholder to "hold" the numbers you find, first[0] is number, and second[1] is length

for i in range(10):

    c = seq(i)

    if c > max[0]: # if the length is > 0 put the new length here (below)

        max[0] = c 
        max[1] = i # once you know the length is greater, you can put the value in the box as well

elapsed = (time.time() - start)

print "The program found the number %s has the longest length at %s, in %s seconds" % (max[1], max[0], elapsed)
```

For instance when I put:

```
seq(10)
```

My output is:

```
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 8]
[4, 3]
[5, 6]
[6, 9]
[7, 17]
[8, 4]
[9, 20]
```

With the first column being the number being evaluated, and second being the counter.

However, when I want to extract the largest counter (second column) using the max = [0,0] data frame, I keep getting this error:

```
The program found the number 0 has the longest length at 1, in 0.00015115737915 seconds
```

But the numbers cannot be 0 and 1, because the output(above) has a max of 20 for the counter ... so the text output should read 9 and 20.

I am probably not understanding the different types of data, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `seq` function should always return a value, but right now it only returns something when x < 1. Put a return statement at the end, too:

```
seq.append(count) # adds all the answers generated to the seq data fram
return count
```

Comment: Because `print` and `return` do completely different things. Without `return`, when `c = seq(i)` executes, `c` will be assigned the `None` value, and consequently `if c > max[0]` will never be true.